# How to make a T-SQL CTE that resolves to a value

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'd like to use CTE-like syntax to define variables in my t-sql, like below.

```
with maxDate as (
        select max(date) from FACT_TBL
    )
   , activeRecords as (
     select * from FACT_TBL_2 
     where date <= maxDate
    )
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work and I get an error when trying to refer to maxDate.   Is there a good alternative to this?  All of the logic needs to be contained with my query and I cannot define a separate function on the database.

Comment: uodate your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: updated to make it more generic instead, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to treat maxDate as a TABLE not as a VARIABLE.

Updated my answer based on new query.

```
with maxDate as (
    select max(date) mDate from FACT_TBL
)
, activeRecords as (
 select * from FACT_TBL_2 
 where date <= (SELECT mDate FROM maxDate) 
)
```